# Xpath to select next parent of the current node

Tags: xpath, import.io

if tr contains `class="productnamecolor colors_productname"` i want to select next `tr` which contains the price details. so i use :

```
.//a[@class="productnamecolor colors_productname"]/parent::node()/following-sibling::tr
```

But didn't work. What is wrong with this expression?

HTML :

```
<tr> 
 <td valign="top" width="100%">
  <a href="unclesamsretailoutlet.com/Trouser-Suspenders-8440015269920-p/…; class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Trouser Suspenders, 2323">Trouser Suspenders</a> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

thanx in advance.

Comment: <tr> 
<td valign="top" width="100%"> 
<a href="http://www.unclesamsretailoutlet.com/Trouser-Suspenders-8440015269920-p/2323.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Trouser Suspenders, 2323"> 
Trouser Suspenders
</a>
</td> 
</tr>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your XML there rather than in a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent of your `<a>` element is a `td` element, and the `td` element doesn't have a following-sibling - certainly not a following sibling that is a `tr`. If you want the next row in the table, use

```
.//a[@class="..."]/ancestor::tr[1]/following-sibling::tr[1]
```

or

```
.//tr[descendant::a/@class="..."]/following-sibling::tr[1]
```

Comment: @Arunkumar: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: sir is there any way to select nth element. like  tr[3],tr[6],tr[9]. Because the <tr> which contains the price details is tr[3],tr[6],tr[9]

Comment: @Arunkumar just change the index in xpath from 1 to which you want...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur can i use (2n+1). i want all the lists from that page.

Comment: @Arunkumar yes you can. But according to xpath you will get only all rows after provided row details..:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select just next `tr` after `<a class="productnamecolor colors_productname">` simply use following two ways :-

- using [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) axis :

  ```
  (.//a[@class="productnamecolor colors_productname"]/following::tr)[1]
  ```
- using [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding)  axis :

  ```
  (.//tr[preceding::a[@class="productnamecolor colors_productname"])[1]
  ```

Hope it helps...:)